# HttpClient angular. Save data in variable and access from other component. Empty or undefined

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular-components

I have a request by get with Httpclient. The problem I have is when i try to access to this variable loaded by this request from other component.
When I try to do it, I find it empty.

This is the method in service:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
  ...
  getBooks(page: string) {
    let url = `${this.urlAPI}books?page=${page}`;
    return this.http.get<Book[]>(url).pipe(map((res: Book[]) => res));
  }
```

This is the code in the component.ts. It is recursive because the api only load 50 by each time.

```
  import { ApiService } from 'src/app/services/api.service';
  ...
  books: Book[] = [];
  ...

  constructor(public auth: AuthService, public _api: ApiService, private router: Router) {
    this.loadBooks(1);
  }
  ...
  loadBooks(page: number) {

    this._api.getBooks(page.toString()).subscribe((resp: Book[]) => {

      this.books = this.books.concat(resp);
      if (resp.length !== 0)
        this.loadBooks(page + 1)
      else{
        ...
      }

    });
  }
```

And this is way to load the variable from child componenet:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { BooksComponent } from '../../tab/books/books.component';
...
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/services/api.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-book',
  templateUrl: './book.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./book.component.scss'],
  providers: [BooksComponent]
})
export class BookComponent implements OnInit {

  book: Book = new Book();

  constructor(private bc:BooksComponent, public _api: ApiService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log(bc.books);
    ...
  }
```

The call to the child component it done after parent. Also I know it is asyncronus call, so until it doesn't finish, I haven't got the variable filled. But I call this after see all data in parent component.
I don't understand why if i have the variable filled, this array is empty from other component.
Thank you by your answers.

**UPDATE:**
This is HTML I use to call to books component:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="detail">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Details </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
         <button mat-button (click)="detail(row.url)">
             <mat-icon>info</mat-icon>
         </button>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

It is part of a table of angular material. I use the function to go to book component.

This the NgModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ListComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    BooksComponent,
    BookComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    APP_ROUTING,
    MaterialModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [ApiService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The parent component is the second code. The rest of the code is about MatPaginator, MatSort or MatTableDataSource.

**UPDATE 2:**

I leave the code in the GitHub: [WikiIceAndFire](https://github.com/JavierBeni/WikiIceAndFire)

Comment: Oh, and BTW,  `this.http.get<Book[]>(url).pipe(map((res: Book[]) => res)) ` makes no sense - you are 'mapping' to the original value. You should change this to `this.http.get<Book[]>(url);`

Comment: yes hehe, I forgot took off it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove `BooksComponent` from the providers array. You don't want the child component to provide its own instance of `BooksComponent`, you want angular to get the already existing one, which is the parent component.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-book',
  templateUrl: './book.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./book.component.scss'],
  providers: [BooksComponent] // <= remove this
})
export class BookComponent implements OnInit {...}
```

There's a tree of components injectors in Angular. When you try to inject something, you just pass the token as a constructor parameter. The component injector starts looking for that token on the component providers. In this case, the component injector found one instance among its own providers, which is not the desired instance (the parent component), so it stopped the recursive search that would take place (by asking the parent's component injector, that would have returned the right instance).

Comment: Thing is if I don't use put the component in the provider, I have this error:

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[BookComponent -> BooksComponent]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[BookComponent -> BooksComponent]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for BooksComponent!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[BookComponent -> BooksComponent]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[BookComponent -> BooksComponent]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for BooksComponent!`

Comment: You shouldn't see any error... it looks like there's something not well structured in your project. It helps finding the problem If you also post the parent component template and the `NgModel` where you declare both of them.

Comment: Thank you Julian. I wrote the NgModule. The error appears when I write in constructor of the Book component or the service: `private bc:BooksComponent`.

Comment: So `BookComponent` isn't a child of `BooksComponent` at all. What are you doing in `detail(row.url)`? This is important. If you're using the router to navigate away to `BookComponent`, chances are that `BooksComponent` is destroyed.

Comment: amm. yes, must be the last. Yes, detail send a url, which is used to go to Book component html. For that everything is destroyed. I thought it keep in memory.

Comment: You can keep `books` in a service instead of in `BooksComponent`. Or, in a more sophisticated scenario, in a centralized store framework, like NGRX or NGXS.

Comment: I tried to keep it in a variable in service. But also when I try to access it from Book, it disapeared. Empty again.

Comment: You're probably providing your service somewhere that is destroyed along with the components. It must be provided in a long-term way. If there's not a problem, don't provide it in any module but decorate it with `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})`, then it'll be a singleton and last as long your app is in memory.

Comment: In the service I have this yes: ´@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})´
I found this: [parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)
Maybe is the solution with the service way.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I notided:
 1. Dont use a `Component` inside `providers` its for `Services` or other `providers` mostly 
 2. Use a Service or `@Input()`/`@Output()` for sharing data between components. 
 3. Try to avoid nested Subscriptions, recursive ones aswell, because this will be a major risk for memory leaks.

Now for my improvement idea: 
I assume the book component is inteded to be a displaying component for 1 book.

this is the `book.component.ts`

```js
    import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
    ...
    import { ApiService } from 'src/app/services/api.service';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-book',
      templateUrl: './book.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./book.component.scss'],
    })
    export class BookComponent implements OnInit {

      @Input() book: Book = new Book();

      constructor(public _api: ApiService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

      }

      ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.book) // either is new Book() or the given book from its parent (look parent .html)
      }
```

```js
...
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/services/api.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs'
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators'

@Component({
  ...
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

...
  books: Book[] = [];

  private loadPage = new Subject<number>()
...

  constructor(public auth: AuthService, public _api: ApiService, private router: Router) {
    //
  } 

  ngOnInit() {

    this.loadPage
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(number => this.loadBooks(number),
        (page, books) => {
          if (books.length !== 0) {
            this.loadPage.next(page+1)
          }
          return books
        }
      )
    ).subscribe({
      next: books => {
        this.books = this.books.concat(books)
      };
      error: () => console.log("error");
    })    
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.loadPage.complete()
  }

  loadBooks(page: number) {
    return this._api.getBooks(page.toString())
  }
```

Api Service remains the same.

and the `parent.component.html`:

```html
<app-book *ngFor="let book of books" [book]="book"></app-book>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. If I delete the provider, I have this Error:
`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[BookComponent -> BooksComponent]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[BookComponent -> BooksComponent]: NullInjectorError: No provider for BooksComponent! `
Also I cannot use Input because I dont call the <app-book>. I am using the HTML code I have updated now in question.
And about subcriptions, I didn't find other way. I want take all data and manage it in my app. And the API only give 50 books by each request.

Comment: OK. So for use cases like these you should use a Service to communicate. For example put the API calls and the books[] array inside a Service which keeps track of them and inject the Service into both components. If you need further help to implement this let me know.

Comment: Thanks you. I go to try this.

Comment: I have done this, but it doesn't work. When I load the BooksComponent, I take the books from service, but like the call to the api didn't finish, so I don't see the list of books. then if I check the books of api, yes, they have books. Even now, the table doesn't update when I set manually the books from the service.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal stackblitz.com reproduction of what you've done? or update the question with your changed code (maybe in a different section so its chronological clear with what you've started). Thanks!

Comment: yes, I have this in github: [WikiIceAndFire](https://github.com/JavierBeni/WikiIceAndFire)

Comment: And i can't find the parent component. Whats its .component name?

Comment: Books isn't the parent component of Book. I access to Book from Books, but routerLink way. In other case, I created a Emitter were a field read when that variable has changed.
With this way, I don't use the provider.